# upload file from subdomain into maindomain

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

this is my domain  [**www.behtop.com**](http://www.behtop.com)  and I have one subdomain  [**www.admin.behtop.com**](http://www.admin.behtop.com)
in www.behtop.com I have image folder that save image and show image from this folder into pages...

in  **www.admin.behtop.com** I have **insert.aspx** page in this page I have fileupload control that I can upload images...

when I select image from fileupload control and click on button it save image in below direction:

```
string path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\../image\\";
```

this is image folder in **www.admin.behtop.com**

now I want when I select image from FUP(fileupload) and click on button it save image in below direction

**www.behtop.com/image**

I mean I want it save image in image folder in **www.behtop.com**  *NOT* in image folder in **www.admin.behtop.com**(from subdomain into main domain)

How I can do it?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

If these domains are on the same server (or network, even) just code the path for the correct folder:

```
string path = "c:\domains\behtop\images\";
```

If you use the Server.MapPath approach, you'll be limited to the current domain, but you can always specify an absolute path which will allow you to write to the correct folder (assuming your account has the correct permissions).